# Clicking on a radio to proceed Javascript Quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick, radio-button

Ok, so here we go: I am creating a javascript quiz. I don't want to use 'next' and 'back' buttons to navigate through the dynamic exam. Instead, I want to be able to click an answer choice, then, after clicking the radio button answer choice, the exam will proceed to the next question automatically.

Here's the link to the code I'm using for the quiz: https://codepen.io/gcarino/pen/LDgtn/

And the code that programs the 'next' button, which should be replaced by any answer choice:

```
   $('#next').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Suspend click listener during fade animation
    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
      return false;
    }
    choose();

    // If no user selection, progress is stopped
    if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
      alert('Please make a selection!');
    } else {
      questionCounter++;
      displayNext();
    }
  });
```

Thanks for everything!